# Entity Framework and MVC4: using a View instead of base table to show parent-child relationship in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a situation where I want to loop the records in a database View, and I want to include child records from a related table. Of course, views don't have "related tables" in a foreign key sense.

When I loop through records of a base table, EF makes it really easy to include related child records. But when a View is the parent, it seems to go haywire. I tried manually creating an association between my db View and related table, but this led to mapping errors, which made sense because there really is no foreign key in the database (and can't be) that represents the relationship.

Hope my question makes sense--I want to display a parent-child relationship in an MVC view where the parent IEnumerable corresponds to a view instead of a base table.

Comment: It occurred to me to create a ViewModel that encapsulates the parent-child relationship, but I don't understand how to load the parents and child records within my controller. All I really understand how to do is return a single query result set. I get lost when I need to include child records.

Comment: Indeed I got this to work with a ViewModel. The tough part was the Linq query just because I'm so unsteady with Linq generally, but I got it working. Anyone curious for the code, let me know.

Comment: public ViewResult Index(int? page = 0)
    {
        int pageSize = 20;            
        var query = db.AllRoutedDocuments.OrderByDescending(row => row.DateCreated).Skip(pageSize * (int)page).Take(pageSize).Select(
                row => new RoutedDocumentIndexItem() {
                    RoutedDocument = row, 
                    RoutingApprovals = db.RoutingApproval.Where(childRow => childRow.RoutedDocumentID == row.ID)
            });
           
        return View(query.ToList());
    }